# Calling suspend function from anonymous Java functional interface

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I using an Java library that has static method with Callable argument. Like:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class TransactionManager {
    public static <T> T callInTransaction(Callable<T> callable) throws Exception {
        return callable.call();
    }
}
```

And I want to create help method in my application to call suspend block as Callable from method of library.

```
suspend inline fun <T> runInTransaction(crossinline call: suspend () -> T): T =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        TransactionManager.callInTransaction {
            call()
        }
    }
```

For `call()` invocation I get an error: "*Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body*".

Is it possible to call suspend function without creating new coroutine?

Comment: No.  Suspend functions can only be called from coroutines.  You can `launch` a coroutine from normal code with the help of a `CoroutineScope`, however.